# How to fit height of ionic app in different devices?

Tags: ionic-framework, hybrid

I have developed hybrid application using ionic framework. While its loading in 3.5 inch screen devices, it comes with a scroll. I need to fit height all devices without scroll. How can i solve this issue with CSS or else?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by using **relative** lengths.

If you assign your elements heights of a total of 100%, they should fit on every screen.